# What is this technic axle?

Tags: technic, part-identification

In this video, Kooberz uses this piece:

[image: part image from video]

You can see it in action [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPCCsYUgj2I) at 15:06. What is the piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular [3 module length axle (4519)](http://brickset.com/parts/design-4519):

[image: 4519]